# Python: Is there any way how I can know under which virtualenv script is running?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm working on project which consists of several subprojects. Each of them uses their own virtualenv. And sometimes I'm not sure that script is running at proper virtualenv. I have a pid of that script in memory.

Is there any way how I know (and be sure that env is correct) under which virtualenv script is running?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you want to know which virtualenv is being used using the PID alone and no other info ? How are these subprojects called ? using subprocess ?

Comment: The have stupid names like lib/main.py, all of them. I don't know is it possible from pid. Do you know any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually decide which virtualenv is running by the absolute path it is. So, from the python script it can be found by next commands:

```
import os
os.environ.get('VIRTUAL_ENV')
```

It will get the path from the environment variable VIRTUAL_ENV which is always defined by script for activating virtualenv.

Comment: System independent solution